# How to find specific files in certain directories?

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I have been stuck about how to approach verifying if a directory exists and to search for a specific file if it does. I have made various attempts, but so far my biggest obstacle has been maintaining security through access modifiers whilst retaining the modular nature of what I'm trying to accomplish.
Goals of the code below:

- Get the user's drives to search for a specific directory.
- Search the drives to find the user's steam directory.
- Look for various executable(s); in this case, the three latest Elder Scrolls games.
- Once those have been detected and verified, perform various actions (launch, check for problems, etc etc)

Yes, I know these things already exist, but I just wanted to get some perspectives on how to perform tasks of this nature. Feel free to offer suggestion and comments of constructive nature about what should be changed, all others will be ignored.

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           string[] drives = Directory.GetLogicalDrives();
           foreach (string d in drives)
           {
               TW_Detection.IDetection.arLoop((File.Exists(d + sd + g)) ? MessageBox.Show(gn + " has been detected in " + d + sd + g).ToString() : MessageBox.Show("The game was not detected!").ToString());
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

The next section of code is my attempt in various ways to create the shortest possible way to perform a series of automated directory searches to find the executable(s).

```
    #region initialDetection
    public class initialDetection
    {
        private string[] games = { "morrowind\\Morrowind.exe", "oblivion\\Oblivion.exe", "skyrim\\TESV.exe" };
        private string[] games_names = { "The Elder Scrolls III: Morrowind", "The Elder Scrolls IV: Oblivion", "The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim" };
        private string[] steamDirectories = { "Program Files\\steam\\steamapps\\common", "Program Files (x86)\\steam\\steamapps\\common", "steam\\steamapps\\common" };
        private void arLoop()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
               string g = games[i];
               string gn = games[i];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
               string sd = steamDirectories[i];
            }
         }
      }
    #endregion

    #region initialDetection
    public class gameDetection : steamDetection
    {
        private string[] games = { "morrowind\\Morrowind.exe", "oblivion\\Oblivion.exe", "skyrim\\TESV.exe" };
        private string[] games_names = { "The Elder Scrolls III: Morrowind", "The Elder Scrolls IV: Oblivion", "The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim" };
        public partial void arLoop()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
               string g = games[i];
               string gn = games_names[i];
            }
        }
     }
    #endregion

    #region precompileDetection
    public class precompileDetection : gameDetection
    {
        static string completeDirectory()
        {
           arLoop();
        }
     }
    #endregion

    #region steamDetection
    public class steamDetection
    {
        private string[] steamDirectories = { "Program Files\\steam\\steamapps\\common\\", "Program Files (x86)\\steam\\steamapps\\common\\", "steam\\steamapps\\common\\" };
        public partial void arLoop()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
               string sd = steamDirectories[i];
            }
        }
     }
    #endregion

    #region Detection Interface
    public interface IDetection
    {
        void arLoop();
    }
    #endregion
 }
```

Yes, I realize this code is very messy and contains a lot uneccessary and broken solutions that are a result of my experimentation. The problem in lies with being able to use the results from the detection to show in a message box that tells the user either the game hasn't been detected or it has and then show the name of the game has been detected.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: you virtually never want a "long version". Keep your question short, to the point and include all (and only) relevant code/information.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, so please edit your post to make it clear what your question is.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel http://sccee.org

Answer (score 1):

```
private string[] games = { "Morrowind.exe", "Oblivion.exe", "TESV.exe" };

public void findGameDirectories(String startDir)
{

    var games = from filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(startDir, "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectory)
                let fileName = Path.FileName(filePath)
                where games.Contains(fileName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                select filePath;
}
```

Comment: There is only one problem with this code that I have encountered so far; [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882577(v=vs.90).aspx) even after trying the solution suggested to resolve the error, a new error ensues.

Comment: Out at a club...will sort out in the morning

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive solution, like below.

```
    private string[] games = { "Morrowind.exe", "Oblivion.exe", "TESV.exe" };

    public void findGameDirectories(String startDir)
    {
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(startDir))
        {
            foreach (var gameFileName in games)
            {
                if (file.EndsWith(gameFileName))
                {
                    // You found the game
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(startDir))
        {
            // Search the subdirectories
            findGameDirectories(dir);
        }
    }
```

This will start in the folder of your choice, and check all of the files within that folder. Then, it will loop through each of the sub-directories, and check each of the files within the subs-directories, and so on until it runs out of subdirectories.

You would probably want to tell the loop to stop once it's found all of the games, but I'll leave that up to you :)

**EDIT :**

I've just found out C# has this very neat little method for listing all files including subdirectories

```
    public void findGameDirectories(String startDir)
    {
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(startDir);

        foreach (var file in directory.GetFiles("*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            foreach (var gameFileName in games)
            {
                if (file.Name == (gameFileName))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You found " + game.DisplayName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dude...have you ever seen [System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Haha, how weird! I just found out about it that very second! I've never really written much C# (i mostly write Java), but I was just about to update my answer :)

Comment: Fair enough...but this is .net queries are done in Linq. Also this is Windows, file name comparisons require `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`. Good attempt given you are a Java dev though.

Comment: You also want to use `EnumerateFiles` not `GetFiles`. The `GetFiles` returns an array with all the files in it. Whilst `EnumerateFiles` returns an object that will yield a new match each time you call `Enumerator.Next` on it. The difference is that one evaluates lazily and thus reduces memory requirements. :P Again...optimization, you code DOES compile and run and give the right answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind (it would make a huge difference if you started at `C:\Program Files`). Out of interest, does the AllDirectories option search recursively, or not? I'm interested to know if it could cause a Stack Overflow, as is the case when using recursive methods like mine.

Comment: Dunno...you would have to consult the framework developers. It would also depend on which framework you are running in (mono/.net/different version/x86/x64/ARM) (e.g. implementation detail, don't care). But at the end of the day. IF FILE SYSTEM IS CAUSING YOUR METHOD TO STACK OVERFLOW, YOU GOT OTHER PROBLEMS.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of infinite recursion, i.e. Desktop has a shortcut to My Documents, which in turn has a shortcut to Desktop

Comment: Shortcuts won't be followed. Hard link/soft links maybe, but those are extremely rare in windows. They are a real pain to create in windows.